# Origin and meaning of the American 1960s slang phrase, "bread is"

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang, money

I am trying to answer a question from a library patron who remembers the entire phrase, "bread is" that she and her friends used in the 1960s.  She accepts that "bread" was used for money or "dough," another slang word.  However she remembers use of the entire phrase, "bread is."

Comment: Hi Cheryl, welcome to ELU. I never heard this "catchphrase" before - perhaps someone else has, but it's a very localised question.

Comment: Was the term _bread is_ alone, or was that part of something longer?

Comment: Fwiw, searches for `"bread is she|if"` and `"hey|wow|man bread is he|said"` at Google Books yield nothing relevant.

Comment: Vote Reopen : curiosity piqued

Comment: @cindi: Offhand I can't think of a single two-word catchphrase/saying consisting solely of some noun followed by a form of the verb *"to be"*. No-one here has managed to find anything to back up OP's "third-hand" assertion that **"bread is"** might have had such status. So what makes you think this question has legs?

Comment: @Fumblefingers: Praise be! - now reopen the question & your mind! :-)

Comment: @cindi: A hit! A palpable hit! Okay, I'll vote to reopen - but if I were a betting man I'd stake any money it's just a mundane shortened *Bread is [the staff of life]*, same as *Praise be [to God]*.

Comment: Just because the phrase is obscure doesn't mean the question is too localized.

Comment: The library patron mentioned that she spoke with people on both the West and East coasts who used this phrase. We spoke at length regarding the meaning of "is" as the third person singular of "be." We concluded our discussion today and she is very appreciative of everyone's participation. I thank you all for your serious answers and allowing me to post this question.  My library patron does not have access to the Internet and was especially pleased to know that her recollection prompted serious discussion.  Thank you again.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking and lack of context.

Answer (score 11):

According to my uncle, who was a university student in the 1960s, "bread is" is a shortened form of the [old proverb](http://proverbhunter.com/proverb/bread-is-the-staff-of-life/), "**Bread is the staff of life.**"

According to the [Facts On File Dictionary of Proverbs](http://books.google.com/books?id=fgaUQc8NbTYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=facts%20on%20file%20dictionary%20of%20proverbs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HFv9TrjhBObZiALCy622Dg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=bread%20is%20the%20staff%20of%20life&f=false), this proverb was first recorded in 1638.

Comment: So you just say 'bread is' to mean 'money'?

Comment: @Kris No, "bread is" was shorthand for "bread is the staff of life," referring to _bread_ in both the literal (foodstuff) and figurative (money) sense.

Comment: My old grandma will always say something like nobody is bigger then bread. I guess it is an old Bulgarian proverb. I have heard "The food makes the fight" like a sports proverb. I guess that here **bread is** indicates that it is bread hat gives you everything as a source of life strength, as it is the juice of life itself, a some sort of nepenthe - an ancient drink for ancient Gods.

Comment: I can't come up with a usage of the abbreviated phrase that doesn't sound frankly awful. Can you give an example of actual usage?

Comment: @Marthaª Many slang terms sound frankly awful out of one's era or generation. ("Word.") According to my uncle, usage went something like: "Well, off to work for The Man." [Rueful shake of the head.] "Well, _bread is_, brother."

Comment: @Gnawme, the library patron appreciated confirmation that others were familiar with this phrase.

Comment: I don't know if it's connected, but Robert A. Heinlein's novel "Stranger in a Strange Land" was pretty popular in the '60s counterculture, and one of its catchphrases was "Waiting is."